# How to reinstall base R package `grid`?

Tags: r, install.packages

I removed the `grid` package in `R` by mistake. Unfortunately I can't install it in the normal fashion i.e., `install.package("grid")` as it is now a base package. I tried re-installing r via `brew install r`. I still can't see the `grid` package in R-Studio. Any tips on how I can re-install this base package?

Comment: How exactly did you remove it? Did you try uninstalling with brew first? Make sure you [know which R that Rstudio is running](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/200486138-Using-Different-Versions-of-R).

Comment: I followed your link and there is only one version. I actually ran `brew install r` without uninstalling. And when I just ran this `brew uninstall r` is gave me this error: `Error: No such keg: /usr/local/Cellar/r`